# Neo4j - NOT IN query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

The graph schema I have is `(actors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movies)`.

I know how to find actors who have worked with a particular actor as below:

`MATCH (actor {name:"Tom Hanks"} )-[:ACTED_IN]->(movies)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(costars)
return distinct costars;`

I know how to find all the actors who have worked in some movie:
`MATCH (all_actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movies) return distinct all_actor;`

However I don't know how to find all actors not in costars. How do I go about it?

Comment: You want to find all the actors (in the entire dataset) that have not starred in a movie with Tom Hanks?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you want to deduct the coactors from the global list of actors this is not the best graph query, here are some suggestions.

```
// Max de Marzi
MATCH (actor:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie), (other:Actor)
WHERE NOT (movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
RETURN other

// Wes Freeman
MATCH (actor:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"}), (other:Actor)
WHERE NOT (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
RETURN other


// Michael Hunger
MATCH (actor:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"} )-[:ACTED_IN]->(movies)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coactor)
WITH collect(distinct coactor) as coactors
MATCH (actor:Actor)
WHERE NOT actor IN coactors
RETURN actor
```

Comment: NOT IN did not work for me. however using <> gave me the desired result

Comment: I think `WHERE NOT actor IN coactors` is right. Am I wrong? Your version doesn't work Michael

Comment: `WHERE NOT thing IN list` worked for me too. Thanks @Gondil

Comment: @michael-hunger `WHERE NOT thing IN list` works correct, but it's awful syntax. Why doesn't cypher not support `WHERE thing NOT IN list`, also?