# Neo4j : Syntax Error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j query for movie database NOT in Query 
 [Neo4j - NOT IN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185463/neo4j-not-in-query)

```
MATCH (actor:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"} )-[:ACTED_IN]->(movies)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coactor)
WITH collect(distinct coactor) as coactors
MATCH (actor:Actor)
WHERE actor NOT IN coactors
RETURN actor
```

While running this query I got Error:

Invalid input 'N': expected whitespace, comment, node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 4, column 13 (offset: 160))
"WHERE actor NOT IN coactors"

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's a small mistake in their example query.

```
WHERE actor NOT IN ...
```

is incorrect syntax (though I wouldn't mind a Cypher update to allow it). It should be

```
WHERE NOT actor IN ...
```

Answer (score 0):

InverseFalcon has the correct answer, but note that the parser tells you exactly where the error is: line 4, column 13.

```
WHERE actor NOT IN coactors
            ^
```

It also tells you what can be expected at that point (including `IN`), and that doesn't include `NOT`.